# JavaScript - Right Pascal pattern with the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: javascript, fibonacci, pascals-triangle

I'm trying to create a Pascal triangle using the Fibonacci sequence. I´m looking for this output:

```
0
0 1
0 1 1
0 1 1 2
0 1 1 2 3
0 1 1 2 3 5
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 
0 1 1 2 3 5
0 1 1 2 3
0 1 1 2
0 1 1
0 1
0
```

This is the code I have written so far. I managed to get the Fibonacci sequence running into a triangle but not the way I want.

```js
function fiboP(n) {
  let string = "";
  let n1 = 0
  let n2 = 1
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      string += n1 + " ";
      next_num = n1 + n2;
      n1 = n2;
      n2 = next_num;
    }
    string += "\n";
  }
  for (let i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
      string += n1 + " ";
      next_num = n2 - n1;
      n2 = n1;
      n1 = next_num;
    }
    string += "\n";

  }
  console.log(string)
}


fiboP(5)
```

```
Output:
0 
1 1 
2 3 5 
8 13 21 34 
55 89 144 233 377 
610 377 233 144 
89 55 34 
21 13 
8
```

I would like to understand what I am missing here and if there is a cleaner and simpler way to produce the desired output.

Comment: first thing you're missing here is resetting values when you go to next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reset your values when you go to next line, you should be able to generate the output you're looking for

```js
function fiboP(n) {
  let string = "";
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    let n1 = 0
    let n2 = 1
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      string += n1 + " ";
      next_num = n1 + n2;
      n1 = n2;
      n2 = next_num;
    }
    string += "\n";
  }
  for (let i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) {
    let n1 = 0
    let n2 = 1
    for (let j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
      string += n1 + " ";
      next_num = n2 + n1;
      n2 = n1;
      n1 = next_num;
    }
    string += "\n";

  }
  console.log(string)
}


fiboP(7)
```

As an improvement i will suggest finding fibonacci sequence once and then just using these values to create this triangle.

Comment: Thanks, it was as as simple as that. This means that every time that it enters into the loop for the new line, starts from 0, right?
And to be sure, the first loop sets the number of rows and when the second loop starts, prints as many elements as the number of the row that is in that particular moment of the loop, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, correct...